# What are the "-P"s in the Berkeley Aligner's output format?

Tags: nlp, machine-translation

I want to use the Berkeley Aligner for some MT research I'm doing, since, apparently, it beats GIZA++ pretty handily (a 32% alignment error reduction in some reported results).  For the most part the outputs in the Berkeley Aligner "examples" directory look like what Moses does to GIZA++ output files (i.e., paired aligned word indices), but there are some funny looking "-P"s after certain pairs.  I can't for the life of me find any documentation  of what these "-P" annotations are supposed to signify (certainly not in the Berkeley Aligner "documentation" directory).

For clarity, I'll give a little illustrative example.  Suppose you have the sentences: "Jean plâit à Marie" and "Marie likes Jean".  French is the source language and English is the target language. The words "Jean" (indices 0 and 2, resp.) and "Marie" (indices 3 and 0, resp.) are aligned in both sentences, and "plâit" and "à " (French indices 1 and 2, resp.) are aligned with "like" (English index 1).  In Moses-post-processed GIZA++ output, this would be denoted by a list of source-target index pairs:

```
0-2 1-1 2-1 3-0
```

Berkeley Aligner produces files that pretty much resemble this, but some index pairs have a -P on them (e.g., you *might* see something like 1-1-P).

What the heck does this mean? Can I safely remove these -P annotations and get a GIZA++-via-Moses style alignment, or should I be doing something more (e.g., multiplying them out into a series of aligned index pairs, or what have you)?

Comment: You can copy the French accents from http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/french.html, or learn how to type them on Windows from the same page.

Comment: Is this comment supposed to be productive?

Comment: And why the H-E double hockey sticks would I do it in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about this but I did a search on the code:

http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22-P%22+package:http://berkeleyaligner.googlecode.com&sbtn=Search

```
    /**
     * Writes the sure and proposed alignments in a modified
     * version of the Pharaoh format.
     *
     * For example, if we have 7 sure alignments and two possibles, we get:
     *
     * enPos1-frPos1 enPos2-frPos2 ... enPos8-frPos8-P enPos9-frPos9-P
     *
     * here, the -P indicates possible alignments.
     */
    public String outputHard() {
            return dumpModifiedPharaoh(false);
    }
```

It seems like these are 'possible' alignments. This is because you have the code set to output 'hard' alignments in Pharaoh(?) format. Seems like you can decide to either use or dump the -P aligments, or switch to the 'soft' output, which gives a strength for each pair and then sweep a threshold parameter.